# MySQL database unable to connection

Tags: java, mysql

I have a private vps, the vps is ubuntu 12.04 using zpanel for phpmyadmin, set up to running a MySQL database already but when I try to connect to the database with Java I am unable to and receive the message:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server."

This is my connection code:

```
package net;

import java.sql.*;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class LoginDatabaseConnection {
    Connection conn = null;

    public static Connection ConnectDB() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://vps35560.vps.ovh.ca/zadmin_login", "*masked*","*masked*");
            System.out.print("Connection Establish");
            return conn;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            System.out.println(e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how long did you keep it running?

Comment: This error shows at startup.

Comment: try it using a bare ip address in the connection uri.  the mysql driver might not be able to resolve the address for that hostname (which can be a common issue with vpn transport configurations).

Comment: I've tried both the ip and url but the same error appears... :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2985169/1391249

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the reason for this problem is DB connection was destroyed, here are some ways for your issue, 
1. append `autoReconnect=true` to the database connection url.
2. due to it's 8 hours long of `wait_timeout` by default for MySQL, so try to modify the configuration file `my.ini` to make it even longer, then  restart MySQL service.
3. it's strongly recommended to use a database source pool, e.g. [c3p0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/), [dbcp](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/), some properties like `validateQuery` and `testOnBorrow` are quite effective for this problem.

Comment: I've added the autoReconnect=true but it still doesnt work
The wait_timeout i believe I've changed it to 24 hours
I do not know what those are so can you please elaborate on them for me? Also I am using MySQL connector from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/ if it helps

Comment: just try the other two ways, and the the 3rd way works for your application absolutely. @Mike Nguyen

Comment: I've done way 1 & 2 but am confuse about how to do way 3

Comment: maybe adding that the vps is ubuntu 12.04 using zpanel for phpmyadmin might help